# Centrifugal force for non uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force, centripetal-force

If a body is under non-uniform circular motion, will it experience or will there be any impact of centrifugal force on the body upon eliminating the centripetal force?
update-sorry.the title of question was incorrect.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. explain

Comment: do you mean the centripetal force to be removed suddenly?

Comment: should probably be pointed out that a body cannot be in circular motion without a centripetal force. At least, I can't think of one in the time it took to write this comment

Comment: How do you "eliminate centripetal force"?

Answer (score 1):

Centrifugal force is a pseudo force; the effects you experience from it are due to centripetal force. If you were to eliminate the centripetal force, you would stop going in circular motion and would also no longer feel any centrifugal "force"